# Is there a way to make Jasmine / Karma throw errors for empty tests?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I recently came across this code in a test in my app:

```
describe('onDestroy', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        this.testSubject.onDestroy();
    });
});
```

No asserts or anything, just an empty describe block with a beforeEach. The problem is that Jasmine/Karma never complained about this test being incomplete/invalid. It doesn't throw any errors or warnings, and it never even calls the `beforeEach()` as `this.testSubject.onDestroy()` would have failed as there was no `onDestroy()` method on the test subject.

Test suites like PHPUnit can be configured to have have a "strict" mode, where tests that lack assertions throw warnings or show up as failures.

Does Jasmine / Karma have a configuration option or a reporter which does the same thing, and throws errors for empty describe blocks (or executes them and lists them as failures?)

Comment: I can see a warning in the karma report  which complains about empty `describe()` karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0"